# Meteor Iron Router Not Passing MongoDB Collection Data into Template

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I created a basic Meteor application with the Iron Router package. Seeded the MongoDB database with some data, and tried to tell Iron Router to serve up the collection to the template. But the data is not coming into the template.

/collections.js

```
Wip = new Mongo.Collection('wip');
```

/app.js

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'masterLayout'
});
Router.route('wip2', {
  path: '/wip2/:shortname',
  template: 'wip2',
  data: function() {
    return Wip.findOne( { shortname: this.params.shortname } );
  }
});
```

There you can see the collection query. Inside the wip2.html file, I have variables like {{name}} and {{shortname}} yet none of them show anything. I confirmed the local MongoDB does have data by doing a "meteor mongo" on the server and running a find:

```
db.wip.findOne( {shortname : 'JonSmith'} );
```

The MongoDB does return data, as shown here:

```
{
  "shortname" : "JonSmith",
  "name" : "Jon Smith"
}
```

To confirm that Iron Router can in fact pass data into the template, I can hard-code the data, which successfully passes data into the template:

/app.js

```
Router.route('wip2', {
  path: '/wip2/:shortname',
  template: 'wip2',
  data: {
    shortname: "JonSmith",
    name:   "John Smith"
  }
});
```

That works. The {{shortname}} and {{name}} within wip2.html do serve up the values.

Any thoughts on why the Collection result is not being served into the template? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you subscribed to the documents in the collection?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but I tried to add a subscription like this in the app.js under the route, but the template waits forever with "Loading..." and nothing happens. ` waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('wip', this.params.shortname);
  },`

Comment: Yea, and you also need to call [Meteor.publish](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish) on the server, with appropriate arguments. Without this publish/subscribe mechanism, the client's collection won't contain any documents (unless you have the added the `autosubscribe` package.

Comment: Thanks.  Publish does fix the problem.  Question, if I do a `return Wip.find();` on the Publish function on the server, does that mean all records in the Collection are accessible by the client? How can I limit their allowed subscribable result set to their allowed records?

Comment: Yes, returning `Wip.find()` in the publish function will send all the documents in the collection to the client. Pass a selector to `find` to limit this to only the documents matching the selector. `this.userId` will refer to the client's user id. Use this to create a selector matching only the documents the user should have access to.

Answer (score 0):

can you try this code,

```
Router.route('wip2', {
  path: '/wip2/:shortname',
  template: 'wip2',
  data: function() {
    templateData = {
        Wip : Wip.find( { shortname: this.params.shortname },{limit : 1} );
     };
  return templateData;
  }
});
```

**findOne** just return an object, whereas **find** with **limit = 1** shall return cursor, which can be used anyway you like.